# How to get the last digit of a number

Tags: c#

How to get the last digit of a number?
     e.g. if 1232123,
    3 will be the result

Some efficient logic I want so that it is easy for results having big numbers.
After the final number I get, I need to some processing in it.

Comment: try a modulus division, dividing by 10 ( % operator)

Comment: the rest of modulo division by 10 IS the last digit :)

Answer (score 80):

Just take mod 10:

```
Int32 lastNumber = num % 10;
```

One could use Math.Abs if one's going to deal with negative numbers. Like so:

```
Int32 lastNumber = Math.Abs(num) % 10;
```

Comment: This is a remainder, not a quotient.

Comment: You should write `int` instead of `Int32`. They are the same but it's easier to read.

Comment: I have never come across a programming task where I had to return the last digit of a negative number.

Answer (score 17):

It's just the number modulo 10.  For example in C

```
int i = 1232123;
int lastdigit = (i % 10);
```

Answer (score 12):

Here's the brute force way that sacrifices efficiency for obviousness:

```
int n = 1232123;
int last = Convert.ToInt32(n.ToString()
                            .AsEnumerable()
                            .Last()
                            .ToString());
```

Comment: lol, i knew this would get downvoted, and it took all of 1ms to happen :)

Comment: obvious compared to what?  modding by 10?

Comment: Neither are particularly obvious!

Comment: If you really want to use `Last()` for whatever reason, you can use it in a better way `int last = n.ToString().Last() - '0'`. Really, use modulo...

Comment: In what way does this sacrifice efficiency? Modulus is a heavy operation from what I'm been told so from my point of view this string approach seems to be the most efficient method. I'm curious to know why that view is incorrect.

Comment: @BjörnLarsson: Taking the remainder is a single instruction that may be ”heavy” because it takes on the order of a dozen cycles in some processors. But converting to a string is a more costly operation that involves calling a subroutine, allocating a buffer, and performing multiple operations.

Answer (score 5):

The best would be:

```
Math.Abs(num % 10);
```

Cause `num % 10` will give you negative result for negative numbers

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do this is `int lastNumber = (your number) % 10;`
And if you want to return the last digit as string you can do this

```
switch (number % 10)
{
    case 0:
        return "zero";
    case 1:
        return "one";
    case 2:
        return "two";
    case 3:
        return "three";
    case 4:
        return "four";
    case 5:
        return "five";
    case 6:
        return "six";
    case 7:
        return "seven";
    case 8:
        return "eight";
    case 9:
        return "nine";
}
```

Comment: should be "five" not fife

Answer (score 1):

Another way is..

```
var digit = Convert.ToString(1234);
var lastDigit = digit.Substring(digit.Length - 1);
```

Comment: The idea is not just give a solution. It is give the best solution, the most efficient solution. Most reliable, easy to understand and everything else.

Comment: @AFetter the solutions above do not work for any number that is not integer.

Comment: I Agree with you