# How to take last digit from long number?

Tags: asp.net, numbers, long-integer

How can I from long number (e.g. 540302405382993021) take just last number (in example is "1")?

Here is my code, where I whant from variable Version take last number (so Variable is long number:

```
var grupe = matchingSpremenljivke.GroupBy(s => s.Version);
```

Ok from coments above I have try this:

```
var grupe = matchingSpremenljivke.GroupBy(s => (s.Version % 10));
```

Is this correct?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Convert the number to string, then access the last index.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the last digit of a number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15731716/how-to-get-the-last-digit-of-a-number)

Comment: @CodeCaster is not mod % 10 as they use fix number, to take. My Long number is always diffrent long.

Comment: I don't understand your comment, but it does work. Try it.

Comment: if there are no negative numbers, then using `%10` should work.

Comment: I have try this: int i = parameters.Version; int lastDigit = (i % 10); and error shows in first line, where it says: 'Cannot convert source type 'string' to target type 'int'

Comment: @geekforfreek that means that "parameters.Version" is a `string` consisting of digits, not a "number". You can't just put that string into an `int` (without parsing). In this case, just use `parameters.Version.Last()`, don't go through an int.

Comment: I see that this question might be duplicate, What shoud I do, do I have to delete question? I do not whant to delet it, because of votes up...

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Int64 testNumber =  -540302405382993021;
string reversed = new string(testNumber.ToString().Reverse().ToArray());
```

`reversed[0]` contains the answer.

This works for negative numbers but does not check for null.

Comment: You could use just `testNumber.ToString().Last()`, if you really don't want to use a "mod 10" approach.

Comment: Used array so that multiple digits could be taken if required.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure on performance of the `Reverse()` method, but isn't `notreversed[stringlength - 1]` more efficient? But it's most likely an unneeded performance gain :)

Answer (score 1):

```
    Dim i As Long = 540302405382993021
    Dim s As String = i.ToString()
    Response.Write(s(s.Length - 1))
```