# How can I select the last digit of an integer in a LINQ .select?

Tags: c#, linq

I have this LINQ select:

```
 var extendedPhrases = phrases
            .Select(x => new ExtendedPhrase()
            {
                Ajlpt = x.Ajlpt,
                Bjlpt = x.Bjlpt,
                Created = x.Created // an int?
            });
```

If I define:

```
public int? CreatedLast { get; set; }
```

Then how can I populate that with the last digit of x.Created?

Comment: not really linq.

Comment: You mean something like `x.Created % 10`?

Comment: Answer isn't really LINQ-specific. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15731716/how-to-get-the-last-digit-of-a-number

Comment: If your number (say `x`) is already an `int`, and you're interested in the last decimal digit in base 10, `x % 10` (modulo operation) should give you the last digit.

Comment: Do you mean the last entry in the list or the last digit of `Created`? It's unclear.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the last digit of a number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15731716/how-to-get-the-last-digit-of-a-number)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are looking for the *last digit* of the `Created` property, the use the [% operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx) like this:

```
var extendedPhrases = phrases
        .Select(x => new ExtendedPhrase()
        {
            Ajlpt = x.Ajlpt,
            Bjlpt = x.Bjlpt,
            Created = x.Created,
            CreatedLast = x.Created % 10
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

The first way to come to mind is to call .ToString().Last():

```
var extendedPhrases = phrases
        .Select(x => new ExtendedPhrase()
        {
            Ajlpt = x.Ajlpt,
            Bjlpt = x.Bjlpt,
            Created = x.Created,
            CreatedLast = x.Created?.ToString().Last()
        });
```

If you aren't using the latest shiny C#, then null protection can be done with:

```
var extendedPhrases = phrases
        .Select(x => new ExtendedPhrase()
        {
            Ajlpt = x.Ajlpt,
            Bjlpt = x.Bjlpt,
            Created = x.Created,
            CreatedLast = x.Created.HasValue ? x.Created.ToString().Last() : null
        });
```

And some conversion back to an `int?` left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: and don't forget to turn it back to int if needed

Comment: Perhaps you should state in your answer what assumption you make about the types of `x` and `ExtendedPhrase.Created`. You appear to assume that `x.Created` is some kind of `Nullable<T>`. Why? Also, you appear to assume that `ExtendedPhrase.Created` is a `Nullable<char>`. Why? -- Long story short, you tried to answer a question that was missing crucial information (namely the types involved).

Comment: @stakx based on the comment in the code of the original question for the `Created` set.

Comment: @petethepagan-gerbil `CreatedLast` is also a nullable `int` so your code will fail as it stands.

Comment: If you assume that `x.Created` and `ExtendedPhrase.Created` are `int?`, then your code is not going to work. As far as I can see, `x.Created.ToString().Last()` will evaluate to type `char`. You cannot assign a `char` to an `int?` property. Also, the expressions in the two clauses of the ternary operator `? : ` do not have compatible types. One expression is a `char`, the other is a null reference (which is an invalid value for a `char` expression). Your code won't compile.